# Using LINQ query two tables bases on matching Ids and return a data structure that has the the id

Tags: c#, linq, azure-table-storage

Imagine a table structure like the above in Azure Table storage.

Table 1

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "partitionkey1" | 101 | test |
| "partitionkey1" | 102 | test |
| "partitionkey1" | 103 | test |
| "partitionkey2" | 201 | test |

Table 2 which is basically a special sublist of prime entities we want to add and remove from

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "partitionkey1" | 101 | true |
| "partitionkey1" | 102 | true |
| "partitionkey1" | 103 | true |
| "partitionkey2" | 201 | false |

Im looking to create a linq query along the lines of

if column A in t1 matches column a in table 2

return a collection of results in the format of ( the left list size is also 10 x the size of the right list )

| AreaName | rowkeys | prime status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "partitionkey1" | 101,102,103 | true |
| "partitionkey2" | 201 | false |

```
            var ACollection = await _ACollectionRepository.GetAll();
            var BCollection = await _BCollectionRepository.GetAll();

            var lft = ACollection.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PartitionKey)).ToList();
            var right = BCollection.Where( x=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PartitionKey)).ToList();

            var joinQuery = (from l in lft
                             join r in right on l.PartitionKey equals r.PartitionKey into joinedList
                             from item in joinedList.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new 
                             {
                                 l.PartitionKey,
                                 ///not sure what to do here ,
                                 item?.prime_status ?? false
                             });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GroupBy to group the items by partition key and then string.Join on to join the rowkeys

```
RowKeys = string.Join(",", bGroup.Select(x => x.ColumnB)),
                PrimeStatus = bGroup.Any(x => x.ColumnC)
```